# Checking a website database column automatically everyday

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, triggers

I'm developing a website using CodeIgniter + MySQL and i've run into a bit of a problem.

I want to make it so that the database checks a table's column(which is of type 'Date) everyday to see if its in the 'past' or not. That is, I want somehow for the database to know if the CURRENT DATE is more than a certain field in a certain table.

If its past the current date, I want another column to be updated.

I am completely at a loss how to do this. I'm assuming it would be a trigger of sorts, but where would I call it , and how do I ensure that its called everyday?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've hosted this on cPanel. Could you guide me as to how to setup a schedule?

Answer (score 6):

You can make a PHP-based [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to [execute a CodeIgniter Controller via CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html).

Example Crontab (will run every day at midnight execute the Controller Cron function execute())

0 0 * * * www-user /usr/bin/php /path/to/codeigniter/index.php cron execute

Then just have the controller perform whatever action you want using either time(), now(), date(), etc as the current day.

Example in cPanel:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Just one thing: Where do I set up the Crontab? I've hosted this on cPanel, but plan to change soon

Comment: In most cPanels, you have a tab called Cron Jobs. You can set this up very easily with the sample code above.

Comment: In cPanel its generally towards the bottom - I've updated the answer to include an example (screenshots) of what it would look like.

Comment: You could, I try to avoid it because it then takes up an apache process.